# Having different associations between two models Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I am building an event app that lets users post events, and other users can 'register' themselves as attending that event. I currently have two models, 'User' and 'Article', where article is the event that a user can post. An article `belongs_to :user` and a user `has_many :articles, dependent: :destroy`.

I am trying to set up a new database to store which users plan to attend an event, in the form of a 'Registration', where it stores a user and the event he plans to attend. This means i need a many to many association between Users and Articles (as a user can attend multiple events, and an event can have multiple attendees). But will this not conflict with the original setting that states an article belongs to a single user?

How do i set this up so my associations dont interfere?

Comment: Not sure I understand your needs. Why do you need Registration table? Why not just have a join table `users_articles`?

Comment: (I think) That is what i am doing, but i am calling it 'Registration' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try either a `has_many through:` or a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship.  Personally, I think I would use a HABTM for this, but the advantage of a HM Through is that there is an intermediate model, which can be used for additional information (such as whether an "attendee" is going or merely interested, etc): http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

As for having multiple *different* associations between the same two models, you can name the association anything you like but specify the class_name of the model you are pointing to: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-and-belongs-to-many-association-reference

For example:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :attendees, class_name: "User", join_table: "articles_attendees", foreign_key: "attended_event_id", association_foreign_key: "attendee_id"
  ...
end
```

And for your User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
  has_and_belongs_to_many :attended_events, class_name: "Article", join_table: "articles_attendees", foreign_key: "attendee_id", association_foreign_key: "attended_event_id"
  ...
end
```

That way you're able to name your association whatever you like, just be sure to keep your singulars singular and your plurals plural, and generally everything readable.  `class_name` should be the name of the model *to which* you are defining the relationship.  `foreign_key` is the database column name containing the ID of the models in which the relationship is defined.  For example, in your User model, `foreign_key` should be the user ID.  The `association_foreign_key` is the column containing the ID of the model to which you are linking.

Also don't forget to create your migration.  Something like this example:

```
class CreateArticlesAttendees < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :articles_attendees, :id => false do |t|
        t.references :attended_event
        t.references :attendee
    end
    add_index :articles_attendees, [:attended_event_id, :attendee_id]
    add_index :articles_attendees, :attendee_id
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :articles_attendees
  end
end
```